# Laravel add values to object based on foreign key

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have a TABLE A called  `diagnoses` . It has a disease_id and a visit_id. I am trying to return the diagnosis from TABLE A along with the disease name and visit details. I keep getting sql syntax errors. Is there a recommended way to push an objects to the array?

My code is

```
public function diagnosis_diseases(Disease $disease) {

        $id = $disease->id;

        $items = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM diseases WHERE diseases.id = '.$id.'  ;'));
        foreach($items as $item){
            $diagnosis = DB::select(DB::raw(' select * from diagnoses
                   where disease_id = '. $id.';' ));

            $items->push($diagnosis);
        }

        dd($items);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use an inner join:

```
public function diagnosis_diseases(Disease $disease) {

        $id = $disease->id;

        $items = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM diseases WHERE diseases.id = '.$id.'  ;'));
        foreach($items as $item){
            $diagnosis = DB::select(DB::raw(' select * from diagnoses
                   inner join diseases on diagnoses.id = ' .$id' '));

            $items->push($diagnosis);
        }

        dd($items);
    }
```